# For every time id1 is within the string in id3, put the id2 part in the new column

Tags: r, stringr, stringi

I would like to generate one additional column to this data frame with some additional information: every time id1 is within the string in id3, replace this portion with its counterpart in id2:

```
 library(tidyverse)



    df1 <- tibble(
         id1 = c("119930", "124659", "114679", "119934", "126821", "124679", "119842", "134863", "133678", "133675"),
         id2 = c("AB1", "AB2", "AB3", "AB5", "AB4", "AB0", "DF1", "FR3", "GTA5", "BA1"),
         id3 = c("", "119934;126821;124679", "", "", "", "119842",  "", "", "", "133678;119930"))
```

This is what I have:

```
    > df1
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   id1    id2   id3                   
   <chr>  <chr> <chr>                 
 1 119930 AB1   ""                    
 2 124659 AB2   "119934;126821;124679"
 3 114679 AB3   ""                    
 4 119934 AB5   ""                    
 5 126821 AB4   ""                    
 6 124679 AB0   "119842"       
 7 119842 DF1   ""                    
 8 134863 FR3   ""                    
 9 133678 GTA5  ""                    
10 133675 BA1   "133678;119930"
```

Result I need:

```
    > df1
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   id1    id2   id3                    id4  
   <chr>  <chr> <chr>                  <chr>
 1 119930 AB1   ""                     ""   
 2 124659 AB2   "119934;126821;124679" "AB5;AB4;AB0"   
 3 114679 AB3   ""                     ""   
 4 119934 AB5   ""                     ""   
 5 126821 AB4   ""                     ""   
 6 124679 AB0   ""                     ""   
 7 119842 DF1   ""                     ""   
 8 134863 FR3   "119842"              "DF1"   
 9 133678 GTA5  ""                     ""   
10 133675 BA1   "133678;119930"               "GTA5;AB1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a base R solution using `strsplit()` + `match()`

```
df1$id4 <- apply(df1, 1, function(v) {
  paste0(na.omit(df1$id2[match(unlist(strsplit(v["id3"],split = ";")),df1$id1)]),collapse = ";")
})
```

such that

```
> df1
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   id1    id2   id3                  id4         
   <chr>  <chr> <chr>                <chr>       
 1 119930 AB1   ""                   ""          
 2 124659 AB2   "119934;126821;1246~ "AB5;AB4;AB~
 3 114679 AB3   ""                   ""          
 4 119934 AB5   ""                   ""          
 5 126821 AB4   ""                   ""          
 6 124679 AB0   "119842"             "DF1"       
 7 119842 DF1   ""                   ""          
 8 134863 FR3   ""                   ""          
 9 133678 GTA5  ""                   ""          
10 133675 BA1   "133678;119930"      "GTA5;AB1"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/12158757/thomasiscoding I think your answer fair enough, but there is one small unwanted thing. If the string in id3 is not in the id1 list for some reason, you code will fill id4 with NA values

Comment: @Marie-Eve in that case, what do you expect for id4?

Comment: Maybe not showing NA. place only id2 values for those id1 existe.

Comment: Alternatively, it would keep the id3 value if a value don't really exist in id1 column

Comment: @Marie-Eve I updated my answer via adding `na.omit()`, so you can try if it works for you

Answer (score 2):

One option involving `stringr` could be:

```
with(df1, str_replace_all(id3, setNames(id2, id1)))

 [1] ""            "AB5;AB4;AB0" ""            ""            ""            "DF1"        
 [7] ""            ""            ""            "GTA5;AB1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Building upon @tmfmnk answer, the complete solution would looks like:

```
    > df1 %>% mutate(id4 = str_replace_all(id3, setNames(id2, id1)))
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   id1    id2   id3                    id4          
   <chr>  <chr> <chr>                  <chr>        
 1 119930 AB1   ""                     ""           
 2 124659 AB2   "119934;126821;124679" "AB5;AB4;AB0"
 3 114679 AB3   ""                     ""           
 4 119934 AB5   ""                     ""           
 5 126821 AB4   ""                     ""           
 6 124679 AB0   "119842;134863"        "DF1;FR3"    
 7 119842 DF1   ""                     ""           
 8 134863 FR3   ""                     ""           
 9 133678 GTA5  ""                     ""           
10 133675 BA1   "133678"               "GTA5"
```